# autodesk Forge Viewer AggregatedView SLOWER than GuiViewer3D?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am working on a Project in React using the Forge (APS) Viewer and need to load multiple models together.

Although I used AggregatedView in a previous project I tried the solution proposed here to load multiple models: [forge-autodesk-load-multiple-models-in-viewer-with-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637125/forge-autodesk-load-multiple-models-in-viewer-with-reactjs)

Then I realized that I needed to Show/Hide models so decided to use AggregatedView instead of GuiViewer3D and loaded the models using AggregatedView.SetNodes instead of GuiViewer3D.loadDocumentNodes

Soon after I noticed that the frame rate had dropped significantly, especially on large models.

The Table below show the difference in Frame Rate when navigating the model:

- Large Model (1.8Gb from 4 Revit files) from 6 FPS in GuiViewer3D to 2FPS in AggregatedView (66% drop)
- Medium Model (200Mb from 1 Revit file) from 24FPS to 12FPS (50% drop)
- rac_advanced_sample_project BIM Walk: from 20FPS to 16FPS (25% drop) (No visible difference in standard navigation)

[image: FPS Table]

In my project I can switch from AggregatedView to GuiViewer3D to load the models so I believe that the FPS difference is only due to the use of one viewer over the other. AggregatedView use GuiViewer3D so I don't understand what is causing this.(Maybe some of the AggregatedView extensions)

Could someone at Autodesk double check this?

Comment: I did more testing and noticed that my FPS drops after a while as I am opening multiple viewers in my project. So I now restart Chrome before testing each scenario. The 1.8Gb models actually run at 26FPS with the GuiViewer3D which is actually super impressive (congrats Autodesk!) with the amount of families in those files (converted with SVF2). When I switch back to AggregatedView and restart Chrome the same models run at 6FPS, which is a big drop. So there is definitely something going on.

Comment: I noticed some z-fighting on the floor geometry in the screenshot from the AggregatedView. Is it possible that you could be accidentally loading the same model multiple times? Try running `viewer.getAllModels()` to make sure that the number of models in the viewer is what you'd expect.